# Finding the occurrence number of searched word from indexed content using lucene 3.6.1

Tags: java, lucene

I am new to Lucene, I want to find the number of occurrence of searched word from indexed content using lucene 3.6.1

First I index the document files and searching from that indexed files.

Can anyone tell me how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resovled using below code:**
`

```
for(ScoreDoc ScoreDoc: scoreDocs){
TermFreqVector[] termsV = reader.getTermFreqVectors(ScoreDoc.doc);
            int termFreq = 0;
            for (int xy = 0; xy < termsV.length; xy++) {  
                String[] terms = termsV[xy].getTerms(); 
                int[] termFreqs = termsV[xy].getTermFrequencies();
                int termcount = 0;
                int count=0;
                for(String str : terms){
                    if(str.equalsIgnoreCase(queryString)){
                        termcount = count;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
                termFreq = termFreqs[termcount];
            }
}
```

`